# OR condition in for loop with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a for loop in which I am looping throw a data table rows.I need to implement a condition in this loop like, loop must execute only 10 times or the number of rows in the datatable (which one is smaller).
example -If datatable have 12 rows loop need to be executed 10 times only.or if datatable have 8 rows loop need to be executed 8 times only not 10.name of my datatable is "dt".
and I had tried some thing like this.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 || dt.Rows.Count;i++ )
```

I believe I can make this logic with a simple regular expression in my code.Can any one point out what need to do.

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching text, not for creating code logic.

Comment: You need boolean `&&` ("and") not `||` ("or").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Alternative using `Math.min`

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(10, dt.Rows.Count); i++)
```

Comment: logic of OP is correct,you are not answering what he has asked

Comment: sorry i read hurriedly and interpreted something else...

Answer (score -1):

```
int cnt=0;
if(dt.Rows.Count < 10)
{
  cnt=dt.Rows.Count;
}
else
{
  cnt=10;
}

for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{}
```